# handling empty strings using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a linq statement that searches a number of fields based on user input from a form.  Only 1 form field is required, thus I need to handle empty string values.  Whats the best way to handle this.  Should i check the length of the string and then null the relevant vars and then check this in my linq statement or can i do something in my linq statement.  My method is below :-

```
     public IEnumerable<Job> GetJobs(string jobNumber, string jobName, string projectDirectorName, string projectManagerName, string groupName) {
        return this._context.Jobs.Where(
            j => j.JobNumber.Contains(jobNumber) ||
                 j.JobName.Contains(jobName) ||
                 j.ProjectDirectorFullName.Contains(projectDirectorName) ||
                 j.GroupName.Contains(groupName));
    }
```

Comment: If you set the variables to `null`, `Contains()` would throw an exception.

Comment: @svick of course but i would check this in my statement.  Just want an idea of how others handle this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use this:

```
 public IEnumerable<Job> GetJobs(string jobNumber, string jobName, string projectDirectorName, string projectManagerName, string groupName) {
    IQueryable<Job> query = this._context.Jobs;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(jobNumber))
       query = query.Where(j => j.JobNumber.Contains(jobNumber));

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(jobname))
       query = query.Where(j => j.JobName.Contains(jobName));

    // etc.

    return query;
}
```

If this will query the database, then that database will only get queried when you iterate over the results of this method, not for each ".Where".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourString);  // .NET 4.0
```

OR

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString);
```

And if it is true, return an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jobNumber)) return _context.Jobs.Where(j => j.JobNumber.Contains(jobNumber));
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jobName)) return _context.Jobs.Where(j => j.JobName.Contains(jobName));
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectDirectorName)) return _context.Jobs.Where(j => j.ProjectDirectorFullName.Contains(projectDirectorName));
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupName)) return _context.Jobs.Where(j => j.GroupName.Contains(groupName));
else throw new ArgumentException ("No arguments specified");
```

Or something that reads better:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jobNumber)) return FilterJobsByNumber(jobNumber);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jobName)) return FilterJobsByName(jobName);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectDirectorName)) return FilterJobsByDirector(projectDirectorName);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupName)) return FilterJobsByGroupName(groupName);
else throw new ArgumentException ("No arguments specified");
```

For suitably defined FilterJobsByNumber etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can helps.

```
    public IEnumerable<Job> GetJobs(string jobNumber, string jobName, string projectDirectorName, string projectManagerName, string groupName) {
    return this._context.Jobs.Where(
        j => (j == null || j.JobNumber.Contains(jobNumber)) ||
             (j == null || j.JobName.Contains(jobName));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be

`String.IsNullOrWhitespace` and `Trim()`

see my code

```
 NorthwindDataContext db= new NorthwindDataContext();
               db.Log = sw;
               var oList = db.Categories
                   .Where(j =>
                            ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text) || j.CategoryName.StartsWith(txtName.Text.Trim()))
                            &&
                            (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDescription.Text) || j.Description.StartsWith(txtDescription.Text.Trim()))   
                          )
                   .Select(p => new { Name = p.CategoryName ,Description =p.Description }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

I think `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` check is the best.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about, but I did not down vote your answer.. My answer is really old and does not match to the topic.. I think they changed the question afterwards, otherwise I would not had suggested this answer. But I never down voted other answers in this topic.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that you have applied `.Trim()` on your search terms before getting into your this code block, modify the code as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Job> GetJobs(string jobNumber, string jobName, string projectDirectorName, string projectManagerName, string groupName) {
        return this._context.Jobs.Where(
            j => (j.JobNumber.Contains(jobNumber) && jobNumber!="")  ||
                 (j.JobName.Contains(jobName) && jobName != "") ||
                 (j.ProjectDirectorFullName.Contains(projectDirectorName) 
                      && projectDirectorName != "") ||
                 (j.GroupName.Contains(groupName) && groupName!=""));
    }
```

The point here is that you don't need to add the if conditions on your search terms. You may have multiple fields for search and it would just work fine.